# Retrieve mongodb documents by some conditions

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I try to retrieve data from a MongoDB collection with Node.JS which meets some conditions. I have a collection called Events which has fields number_of_persons, category and users_attended. An example of event document:

```
{ 
    "category":"123",
    "number_of_persons":3,
    "users_attended":["345","456","567","786"]
}
```

Users_attended is a ref to UserAttended collection which has fields id,user,accepted and canceled.
Example:

```
{
   "id":"345",
   "user":"1",
   "accepted":true,
   "canceled":false
}
```

The query has an array of categories like **['123','1234','12345']**, and i should return all events which have category id in this array. Also, categories vector can be empty array, and in this condition, i should return all events without filtering by category. Another condition for query is if the user_attended reference have a number of entries which have **accepted=true** and **canceled=false** less than the number of people of event(3). I should do this with aggregation, i tried to do with $in operator for category and with $map for user_attended but no results. Can someone help me?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, this statement: _"Another condition for query is if the user_attended reference have a number of entries which have accepted=true and canceled=false less than the number of people of event(3)"_ is not clear can you elaborate?

Comment: @DheemanthBhat yes sure. An user can join for an event. When he join an event, he will be inserted in UserAttended collection(id:1, user:345, accepted:false, canceled:false) and his ref will be inserted in user_attended field from Event collection(eg. for event document: {id:"1", category:"123", user_attended:["1"], number_of_persons: 5. Every user which attend for an event can be accepted (accepted will be set to true) or rejected(accepted will remain false).

Comment: @DheemanthBhat When i search for an event, i should return just events which have available slots(number of user_attended who has field accepted set to true is lower than number_of_persons of event).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your manager file (node.js file containing queries) put this condition to skip checking for `categories` when it is empty.

```js
let condition = {};
if(Array.isArray(categories) && categories.length > 0) {
  condition = {
    "category": {
      $in: categories // Can have values like ["1234", "123"]
    }
  }
}

eventsModel.aggregate([
  { $match: condition },
  // Rest of the query as shown below
```

Try this query:

```js
db.events.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            "category": {
                $in: ["1234", "123"]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "UserAttended",
            let: { users_attended: "$users_attended" },
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match: {
                        "accepted": true,
                        "canceled": false,
                        $expr: { $in: ["$_id", "$$users_attended"] }
                    }
                }
            ],
            as: "users_attended"
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            $expr: {
                $gt: ["$number_of_persons", { $size: "$users_attended" }]
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

Output:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60310979127fac3244c8f0d9"),
    "category" : "123",
    "number_of_persons" : 3,
    "users_attended" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("603108bf127fac3244c8f0d3"),
            "user" : "1",
            "accepted" : true,
            "canceled" : false
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("603108bf127fac3244c8f0d4"),
            "user" : "2",
            "accepted" : true,
            "canceled" : false
        }
    ]
}
```

This how my `events` collection looks like:

```js
/* 1 createdAt:2/20/2021, 6:37:05 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60310979127fac3244c8f0d9"),
    "category" : "123",
    "number_of_persons" : 3,
    "users_attended" : [
        ObjectId("603108bf127fac3244c8f0d3"),
        ObjectId("603108bf127fac3244c8f0d4"),
        ObjectId("603108bf127fac3244c8f0d5")
    ]
},

/* 2 createdAt:2/20/2021, 6:37:05 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60310979127fac3244c8f0da"),
    "category" : "1234",
    "number_of_persons" : 3,
    "users_attended" : [
        ObjectId("603108bf127fac3244c8f0d6"),
        ObjectId("603108bf127fac3244c8f0d7"),
        ObjectId("603108bf127fac3244c8f0d8")
    ]
}
```

This is how my `UserAttended` collection looks like:

```js
/* 1 createdAt:2/20/2021, 6:33:59 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("603108bf127fac3244c8f0d3"),
    "user" : "1",
    "accepted" : true,
    "canceled" : false
},

/* 2 createdAt:2/20/2021, 6:33:59 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("603108bf127fac3244c8f0d4"),
    "user" : "2",
    "accepted" : true,
    "canceled" : false
},

/* 3 createdAt:2/20/2021, 6:33:59 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("603108bf127fac3244c8f0d5"),
    "user" : "3",
    "accepted" : false,
    "canceled" : false
},

/* 4 createdAt:2/20/2021, 6:33:59 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("603108bf127fac3244c8f0d6"),
    "user" : "4",
    "accepted" : true,
    "canceled" : false
},

/* 5 createdAt:2/20/2021, 6:33:59 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("603108bf127fac3244c8f0d7"),
    "user" : "5",
    "accepted" : true,
    "canceled" : false
},

/* 6 createdAt:2/20/2021, 6:33:59 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("603108bf127fac3244c8f0d8"),
    "user" : "6",
    "accepted" : true,
    "canceled" : false
}
```

Comment: Thanks you so much for your answer Dheemanth, i think it is correctly, but i have a problem. In UserAttended collection i don't have "id" field, i have just "_id" which is a ObjectID, and this reference is inserted in user_attended array. How can i match by _id? I try to replace "$id" with "$_id" in match expression but no results...

Comment: Replacing `$id` with `$_id` worked for me. Check the updated answer. Post your `events` and `UserAttended` schema, you might me missing something there.

Comment: Also post the code where you have written this query if possible. Check for typos.